# Magento 2 - where to find "confirmation" attribute for customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, eav, eav-attributes

Where is the status of "Confirmed email" saved in the database?

How can I change the value directly in the database for this customer?

[image]

I searched everywhere, but I can't find the table where this relation between customer and attribute is stored.

I searched in

```
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
customer_entity_int
```

Comment: SELECT entity_id,confirmation,email FROM `customer_entity`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is static attribute you could not find it on above three table.

it would save in "customer_entity" table itself.

Execute Below query for more details.

```
SELECT entity_id,confirmation,email FROM `customer_entity`;
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE (`attribute_code` LIKE '%confirmation%');
SELECT * FROM `customer_eav_attribute` where attribute_id in (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE (`attribute_code` LIKE '%confirmation%'));
```

Any eav_attribute which value is **static** in **backend_type** column, That value would saved in main table ( for product = catalog_product_entity , for customer =  customer_entity, ..)

For track,

Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo.php :: getIsConfirmedStatus

Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::getConfirmationStatus